# Como iterar un entero en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera saber como podira iterar sobre un entero para un bucle 'for' ya que python solo permite iterar sobre strings.
Quiero que pase esto: dado un entero que tenga dos o mas digitos devuelva la suma de todos sus digitos.

```
def suma_digitos(n):
   suma = 0
   for i in n:
      suma += i
   return sum
```

Comment: Puedes convertir el entero a `str` e iterar sobre él. Luego cada elemento lo conviertes de nuevo a `int` y haces la suma. En comprensión de listas sería: `sum([int(x) for x in str(n)])`

Comment: @aeportugal agrega eso como respuesta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una técnica sería convertir el entero a cadena, iterar normalmente sobre esa cadena y sumar cada elemento convertido nuevamente a entero.

```
def suma_digitos(n):
    suma = 0
    for i in str(n):
        suma += int(i)
    return suma
```

Otra forma similar, pero usando comprensión de listas:

```
def suma_digitos(n):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

también se podría:

```
def suma_digitos(n):
    suma = 0
    for x in range(len(f"{n}")):
        q,r = divmod(n,10)
        n = q
        suma+=r
    return suma
    
print (suma_digitos(1586))
```

donde es cierto que for recorre iterables y un entero no lo es, por lo tanto engañamos con:

```
range(len(f"{n}"))
```

es una representación formateada del largo del entero pero no una conversión en sí.

La función divmod hace una división, pero  devuelve dos valores: el cociente y el residuo

```
q,r = divmod(n,10)
```

esto usa el siclo sobre un entero y obteniendo cada una de sus partes, supongo que el resto está más que claro.